# How to save and send cookie in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Server api is design for web page.
When I login successfully by login api, it will set the cookie into browser automaticlly. Other requests will carry the cookie automaticlly.
What should I do in Flutter?

e.g.
in browser:

```js
const res = await axios.get('/login', {params: requestParams})
// res is '' (empty string)
```

in Flutter:

```dart
dynamic res = await dio.get("/login-api")
// res is '' (empty string),
// the cookie is not set, and I don't know where to find the cookie.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To set and use cookies in Flutter, you can use the **cookie_jar** package. This package provides a simple way to store and manage cookies for HTTP requests.

also checkout this link :  https://pub.dev/packages/cookie_jar

Here is an example of how to set and use cookies in Flutter:

```
import 'package:cookie_jar/cookie_jar.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

void main() async {
  // Create a CookieJar object.
  final cookieJar = CookieJar();

  // Set a cookie.
  cookieJar.set('my_cookie', 'my_cookie_value');

  // Create a Dio client.
  final dio = Dio();

  // Pass the CookieJar object to the Dio client.
  dio.cookieJar = cookieJar;

  // Make an HTTP request.
  final response = await dio.get('/login-api');

  // Check the response status code.
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // The login was successful.
  } else {
    // The login failed.
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the dependency for Dio https://pub.dev/packages/dio_cookie_manager/versions/2.1.4